# Java - Incrementing Numbers using for loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, increment

I have attempted to complete the following exercise however the output isn't as expected.

You should print a number of pluses equal to the number entered by the user, followed by a list of numbers, so that in total exactly 20 characters are printed. The numbers printed should be the last digit of the current position in the list. Example: +++++678901234567890 if the number entered by the user was 5.

Here's my code:

```
package interact;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Interact {


    public static void main(String[] args) {



        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

            {int value,k
            for (int i=0; i<num1; i++) {
                System.out.print("+");}


                        for (int j=0; j<20-num1; j++) {

                            if (num1>9) {k=num1-10;}

                            else k=num1+1;
                            System.out.print(k);

                }

}
```

The output if 6 is entered is ++++++77777777777777. The numbers aren't incrementing - why not?

Comment: Your code does not compile. I do not see you defining num1? Please post a mcv example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You aren't incrementing k or num1, so k becomes whatever number the user enters + 1, and keeps printing that out. You need to update k. First set k=num1. Then change your loop to:

```
if (k>9) {k=0;}
    else k++;
    System.out.print(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, your num1 remains same throughout the below loop.

```
for (int j=0; j<20-num1; j++) {

                if (num1>9) {k=num1-10;}

                else k=num1+1;
                System.out.print(k);

    }
```

But if you do like this it'll work

```
           k=num1+1;
       for (int j=0; j<20-num1; j++) {
                    if (k>9) {k=0;}
                    System.out.print(k);
                    k++;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it for you :) 
i can answer any questions you got on the modification :) 
good luck :)

```
int value, k;

        for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
            System.out.print("+");
        }

        k=num1;

        for (int j = 0; j < 20 - num1; j++) {

            if (k >= 9) {
                k = 0;
            }

            else
                k++;
            System.out.print(k);

        }
```

Comment: That does work, however when the counter gets past 9, the counter is supposed to go back to 01234 rather than going into double figures :/